# shared_ptr object global deletion

Tags: c++

I wanted to use a smart pointer like shared_ptr of std library but where
it would be possible to delete the object for every shared_ptr that share it
without deleting those pointers.

For example if i use std::shared_ptr

```
shared_ptr<A> p1 = make_share<A>();
shared_ptr<A> p2 = shared_ptr<A>(p1);
p1.reset();
// now p2 still contain the object of type A
// instead of nullptr
```

Is there a way to do that or does some alternatives exist? Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: You are kind of doing it wrong. The purpose of shared_ptr is that the object only gets destroyed when no-one uses it anymore. So you are using the kind of pointer who is tryning to inhibit the thing you want to do.

Comment: Is it me or does your description appear to contradict your code example? Shared pointers already work according to your coding example.

Comment: Sry, my explanation may be bad. I meant, exist something else as shared_ptr which could have p2 to be a nullptr after p1.reset() ?

Comment: @pepece a pointer to a pointer can do that. But in general each pointer is it's own so you cannot change the value of each. You can try to make the object it points to as "invalid" though. Or have a pointer to a pointer and make the inner one null

Comment: @pepece In your code example you say you don't want `p2` to be `nullptr` after `p1` release. Can you edit the code to say what you said here in comments?

Comment: Looks like a static initialization fiasco.

Comment: @DieterLücking: I don't think we are to assume that `p1` and `p2` are `static` (or file-level scoped) in the example.

Comment: Thanks. In a way i already tried that coding my own smart pointer but i was blocked by inheritance issue(upcast downcast). And it seems it will be the same problem.

Comment: @Galik actually i  wanted  to say that p2 should be  `nullptr` in my comment. Is my english wrong?

Comment: @DieterLücking There is nothing static, it is just to have a short example.

Comment: @pepece I'm just reading it wrong. Sorry. I see now you are saying what the current situation is rather than what you prefer it to be.

Comment: @Quentin probably has the right answer for what you need, I believe.

Comment: @Galik No problem. Thanks for the answers...

Comment: Why not to store a reference to `shared_ptr` in `p2` like this: `shared_ptr<A>& p2=p1` ?

Comment: Use a weak_ptr .When all the strong ref are deleted, weak_ptr will automatically detach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. `std::shared_ptr` comes with [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), a pointer that can point to an object managed by a set of `std::shared_ptr`s and check whether it is still alive, but does not extends the object's lifetime.

You just have to keep the original `std::shared_ptr` to your object, and lend `std::weak_ptr`s to other users of that object. When the object must be destroyed, reset the `std::shared_ptr`, and all remaining `std::weak_ptr`s will be able to tell (they'll return null `std::shared_ptr`s when the users try to lock them).

Comment: Good idea. It kind of what i was looking for. The only issue is that i might not be the only one to use that code is there a way to spur overs into not beeing able to copy a created  `shared_ptr` except if it's for a `weak_ptr`?

Comment: @pepece do you mean preventing other users from creating `std::shared_ptr`s ? Not out-of-the-box, but an API exposing only `std::weak_ptr`s clearly indicates that the users should not hold onto the locked pointers for longer than necessary. You *could* write a wrapper around `std::weak_ptr` to create non-movable lock objects.

Comment: Exactly. Are you talking about std::reference_wrapper because i don't see what you are meaning?

Comment: @pepece not at all. I mean writing a small class which contains a `std::weak_ptr`, and provides locking and access through `operator->`, but without ever exposing the `std::weak_ptr` or the `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean. At least, it seems to work in my context. Great thanks =)